# NaN's are getting reported as 0 while compiling with icpx and not as NaN

Tags: intel, armadillo, intel-oneapi, dpc++

On running this program, in the output Nan"s are being reported as 0, when building with icpx V2022.1, it is working fine with other compilers.

```
Compiling with the command:  icpx -O3 -qmkl=sequential
```

```html
#define ARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER

#include <armadillo>

int main() {
  
  arma::Col<double> var;

  var.randu(4);
  var.print();
  
  std::cout << std::endl;
  
  var[0] = arma::datum::nan; 
  // Same with var[0] = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN()
  var.print();
  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If ICPX is like ICC, it might be defaulting to `-fp-model=fast=1`.  ([performance of icc main.cpp == g++ -ffast-math main.cpp](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/20815)).  So it might not be respecting NaN, maybe try compiling with `-fno-fast-math` or `-fp-model=precise` to see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Intel compilers' default optimization setting is -O2.
As suggested by Peter Cordes in the above comment, You can use the command"-fp-model=precise" flag, to instruct the compiler to strictly follow value-safe optimizations when implementing floating-point computations.
Hope this solves the issue.